# PHP script not updating mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

this script is simply not working... can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$shortdesc = $_POST['shortdesc'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$target = $_POST['target'];
$sort = $_POST['sort'];
$html = $_POST['html'];

    include('appvars.php');

    $query = "UPDATE insight SET name='".$name."' AND SET date='". $date . "' AND SET html='" . $html . "' AND SET shortdesc='" . $shortdesc . "' AND SET link='" . $link . "' AND SET target='" . $target . "' AND SET sort='" . $sort . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";

    mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: put `echo($query);` after the SQL query to see what is being passed

Comment: @tunmisefasipe, most fundamental and the must thing to do :) +1

Comment: call [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after the query to check if it returns any errors. This is a good practice in general

Answer (score 5):

You aren't [escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) your values so you are vulnerable to SQL injection and also construction of invalid statements. For example, if any of your input strings contain an apostrophe then it could cause your code to fail.

Have a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) that will make it much easier to construct your queries with [parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

In your query you will also need to use commas instead of `AND SET`.

```
$query = "UPDATE insight SET name='foo', date='2012-12-10' WHERE id=42";
```

The syntax for UPDATE is described in the MySQL documentation:

- [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Comment: not worried about that right now. not a public form, only for my own use.

Comment: @user1427274 Escaping values isn't about security; it's about correct interpretation.  Security just happens to be a byproduct.

Comment: will i still be able to insert html if I escape values?

Comment: @user1427274: Yes of course. It's unlikely to work if you don't.

Comment: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in case you're wondering what they are. You could also use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
$query = "UPDATE insight SET name='".$name."' ,date='". $date . "' ,html='" . $html . "' ,shortdesc='" . $shortdesc . "' ,link='" . $link . "' ,target='" . $target . "' ,sort='" . $sort . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
```

Comment: used this, it set 'name' to 0, rather than the given "testing" and the rest of the values were unaffected.

Comment: It may due to the data type of column you set. You should set that to **`text`** or **`varchar`** to accept non numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Its working ... check now

```
 $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $shortdesc = $_POST['shortdesc'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $target = $_POST['target'];
    $sort = $_POST['sort'];
    $html = $_POST['html'];

        include('appvars.php');

       $query = "UPDATE insight SET name='".$name."' ,date='". $date . "' ,html='" . $html . "' ,shortdesc='" . $shortdesc . "' ,link='" . $link . "' ,target='" . $target . "' ,sort='" . $sort . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";



        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I aint a pro at mysql, but a try.

I guess `id` is an integer. So, dont quote it.

Try this,

```
$query = "UPDATE insight SET name='".$name."' , date='". $date . "' , html='" . $html . "' , shortdesc='" . $shortdesc . "' , link='" . $link . "' , target='" . $target . "' , sort='" . $sort . "' WHERE id=". $id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQL syntax is not correct, you can use it like this: `UPDATE tablename SET rowname = value , ....`